# Using elements of a Hash as radio Button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application in which a user can create a sport, also any user can register to the sport by selecting it. I'm trying to use radio buttons as i intend for any user to be able to select more than one, but i'm having issues with `radio_button_tag` and `collection_radio_button` . `collection_radio_button` only shows one option and both still needs a label. I want to be able to pass the sports created in the view (using radio button) as a hash so that it can be dynamically increased or reduced as the sports are created by users. Also please is there another option that's workable and not necessarily radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,the scenario should allow user to add multiple sports.so you should use checkboxes and  the code is 
`<label>Cricket<input type="checkbox"/></label>`

Comment: Yes, but my issue is having to hard code the label and having a bunch of label-input type lines... What would then happen a user creates a sport that wasn't hard coded into the view?