# Ruby Loops not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I recently asked a question about using some values in a hash for the labels of either radio buttons or check box in a rails form instead of hard coding in the label: [Using elements of a Hash as radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235931/using-elements-of-a-hash-as-radio-button). I tried to solve this by creating a helper method that takes in the hash(basically a table in my database) and maps the required parameter into an array but looping through the array; while using the parameters as a label hasn't produced the desired result, it outputs the value of iterator instead of outputting the result of the lines of code i wrote. Below is my helper method.

```
def sport_select(sport)
 x = Sport.all.map {|e| e.sport_name}
 for i in 1..x.length
   check_box_tag(x[i], checked_value = 1, unchecked_value = 0)
 end
end
```

The line `x = Sport.all.map {|e| e.sport_name}` produces `["sport_name", "sport_name"]`; but the for loop only shows `1..2`. I have tried changing `x = Sport.all.map {|e| e.sport_name}` to `x = Sport.all.map {|e| [e.id, e.sport_name]}`  to use it as a hash, which produces `[[id, "sport_name"],[id, "sport_name"]]` but i have had issues using the `id` as the key to the hash. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What result are you hoping to see?  `1..2` is the return value of the for loop, which becomes the return value of the method since that's the last line.  Can you display your `check_box_tag` method?  That may help to see what you're looking for.

Comment: You can just experiment in the console to build up your code if you're not sure what you're doing.

Comment: `check_box_tag` method? I referred to: <http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag>

Comment: ah... so this is really designed to be used within an .erb file as a View, not within a helper method.  The code is generating HTML, but it never shows up anywhere, as - again - the return value of the method is `1..2`

Comment: Thanks @dwenzel . I forgot about the extension and how it affects the HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't sane:

```
check_box_tag(x[i], checked_value = 1, unchecked_value = 0)
```

The method definition is:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

You're passing 1 for `value`, and 0 for `checked`. You cannot "name" parameters with `variable = value`, all you're doing is setting a variable and then passing the same value through to the method.

If you want to produce a checkbox where the name is the sport's name and its value is the id of the sport, get rid of your pair of loops and just us a *single* loop:

```
def sport_select(sport)
  Sport.all.map do |e|
    check_box_tag(e.sport_name, e.id)
  end
end
```

If you're outputting the result to a page, you will also probably want to use `.join('').html_safe` to return a single string, and prevent it from being escaped.

Comment: To think that i had tried something similar in `Sport.all.map {|e| check_box_tag(e.sport_name, checked =1) }` . Thanks for catching and explaining my error.

Answer (score 0):

This should display all the Sport records as radio buttons:

```
def sports_as_radio_buttons(sports = Sport.scoped)
  html = "".html_safe
  sports.each do |sport|
    html += radio_button_tag('sport_id', sport.id, id: "sport_#{sport.id}")
    html += label_tag("sport_#{sport.id}", sport.name)
  end
  html
end
```

Hope this helps!